# Integral of displacement

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, coordinate-systems, integration, displacement

Can somebody explain to me what is the integral of displacement $x$ with respect to time (if it is anything significant)? In high school physics, we are thought derivatives of $x$ which are velocity, acceleration etc. But what does it’s integral signify?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of the integral of position?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/223993/)

Comment: With respect to what ? You mean $\int x \mathrm{d}t$ or $\int x \mathrm{d}x$ or something else ? Integration without a variable defined doesn't makes sense.

Comment: @EmilioPisant To some extent it does but I am looking for a more precise answer. Like what is the physical significance of that quantity and if it has a special name.

Comment: @iAmSecretlyFlash That object has been treated multiple times on this site already. You should search thoroughly and, if you still have not found an answer, you should edit this post explaining the similar threads you have found and why they don't meet your needs.

Comment: ... but, that said: not all quantities one can write down (regardless of how simple) have widely-understandable physical interpretations or well-recognized special names. There are threads on this site that explain the limited cases in which the object $\int x(t)dt$ is useful, but having an expectation that it "must" have a dedicated name is, shall we say, bound to be harshly treated by reality.